# Static Script file overrides the GET method Server-side Rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, server-side-rendering

Repository- https://github.com/sapinder-pal/Rest-Countries-App-ReactJS-SASS

I'm trying to transform my React app to SSR system. Although it works on ***localhost*** but throws an application-error when deployed to **Heroku**. The build logs show ***success***, but an **Application error** is thrown on visiting the url.

PLEASE see the **EDIT 1** where I've stated the root error.

**Application Logs-**

```
2020-09-21T05:23:05.915898+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! rest-countriers@1.0.0 start: `node server/index.js`
2020-09-21T05:23:05.916046+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-09-21T05:23:05.916211+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-09-21T05:23:05.916335+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the rest-countriers@1.0.0 start script.
2020-09-21T05:23:05.916489+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-21T05:23:06.005989+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-21T05:23:06.006055+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-21T05:23:06.006056+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-21T05_23_05_918Z-debug.log
2020-09-21T05:23:06.234287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-21T05:23:06.275353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**server/index.js**-

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
        plugins: ['@babel/transform-runtime']
});

require('./server');
```

**server/server.js**-

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from '../src/App';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Some error happened');
        }

        const context = {};
        const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                <App />
            </StaticRouter>
        )
        
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${app}</div>`
      )
    );
    });
    
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App launched on ${PORT}`);
});
```

**EDIT 1-**

Looks like I've found the root error but don't quite know the reason-

```
/**** app.get() WORKS ONLY IF I DON'T SERVER THE 'BUILD' FOLDER. ****/
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./build')));

/**** This function doesn't log anything if the *build* folder is served.
I got assured when I visited **Network** tab in devtools where I saw that
the *initial preview* for html file is blank, which means the file is not
rendered server-side ****/
app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    console.log('got request');
    ....
}
```

I have *index.html*, *index.css* and *index.bundle.js* in the *build* folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

There were two issues with the code-

1. The first one being that the `app.get()` method doesn't run was solved by moving `app.use()` statement below the former one.

However, I still don't quite understand the reason for this, because I think a *middleware* would still run **before** the callback function in the route method. If you know what's happening here, please let me know through comments!

2. The second issue, which made the `start` script fail, was because I was using `@babel/core` as a ***dev-dependency***. So I re-installed it as a ***dependency*** only, and that fixed the error.

***I'll still appreciate if anyone could explain the first point to me!***

Answer (score 0):

You need to add heroku-postbuild command in your package.json
Your command would be something similar to

```
scripts:{
    ...
    "build": ***,
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build",
}
```

this will run and install your dependencies and will run the build command.

Try removing 'return' keyword

```
res.send(
data.replace(
 <div id="root"></div>',
 <div id="root">${app}</div>`
 )  
)
```

port should be
process.env.PORT || 3000

That's it. It should probably work now.

Comment: Although I already had the `postinstall` script and while I don't know what extra `heroku-postbuild` would do, I tried by adding it to the file but I still get the application error. However the logs are a bit different this time.

Comment: I've edited the question with newer logs for your solution. Please have a look.

Comment: i have edited the answer, you can try this solution by updating PORT

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't work! I've replaced the logs for your answer with recent ones. Please read the logs!

Comment: Try commenting RenderToString and just return some random string. See if it works!   Is your application running fine in local environment?

Comment: I've found the root error but don't know what cause this error. Please see the edited question! Help me out please!